# How can I detect using @bot.commands if another different user (other than the bot) is mentioned in a Discord guild with the discord.py API?

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py, bots

A friend and I have been designing a simple Discord bot to use in a guild (server) with the official Python API. The following is the code we are using (with repl.it, the browser-based IDE):

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("The bot is ready to be Bob as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  msg = message.content

  if msg.startswith("hey"):
    await message.channel.send(":)Sup My Dude")

  if msg.startswith("hi"):
    await message.channel.send(" :)Sup My Dude")

  if msg.startswith("Sup"):
    await message.channel.send(":) Sup My Dude")

  if msg.startswith("hello"):
    await message.channel.send(":)  Sup My Dude")

  if msg.startswith("bob") or msg.startswith("joe") or msg.startswith("jeff") or msg.startswith("john") or msg.startswith("mega jeff") or msg.startswith("ultra john") or msg.startswith("super bob") or msg.startswith("mr.names") or msg.startswith("sloppy joe") or msg.startswith("billy bob"):
      await message.channel.send("you forgot the rest but, your the man")

  if msg.startswith("xkill"):
    await message.channel.send("With what weapon though one word answer")

  if msg.startswith("ax"):
    await message.channel.send("ooh nice choice")

client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

As you can see above, I've been using the basic @client.event command in order to start my async functions. However, I want to make it so that if a specific user is mentioned, then the bot will respond with something. For example, if I typed this in my Discord server:
**@Mr.Names**

That would be a mention that is mentioning a specific user. How can I make my bot work with the current code I have so that it can identify when this user is mentioned, and based on if the user is mentioned or not, send a message in the server? I'm using Python 3.8.5 with repl.it, which is an online IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the attribute [`mentions` of the Message class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.mentions) that contains a list of all the user mentionned in a message. You can then iterate over this list and compare their id with the specific user you need

Simply add this code

```
for user in message.mentions:
    if user.id == specific_user_id:
        await message.channel.send("Specific user mentionned")
```

in your on_message function and replace `specific_user_id` by the user id of the person you need your bot to notice

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked perfectly, and now the bot responds when a specific user is mentioned in a message. Thanks again!